# How to select an option in a dropdown list angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS directive and I need to set a selected option of a dropdown list in my template.

```
<select id="energySource" ng-options="o.name for o in energyOptions" ng-model="energy" ng-selected="energy" ng-change="energyChange();"></select>
```

The content of the optionlist depends on resources send by a server when the page is loaded.

```
var energyChosen = "All";


      angular.element(document).ready(function () {

          $.get('/Dashboard/GetResources', function (data) {

              scope.Resources = data;

              scope.energyOptions = [{ name: scope.Resources.Electricity, id: "Electricity" }, { name: scope.Resources.Gas, id: "Gas" },
               { name: scope.Resources.Water, id: "Water" }, { name: scope.Resources.Solar, id: "Solar" }];

              scope.energy = scope.energyOptions[0];
              energyChosen = scope.energy.id;

              scope.$apply();

          });
```

It works except that a blank option is preselected which disappears when i select an option
I would like to be able to preselect one option. I thought that

```
scope.energy = scope.energyOptions[0];
```

would do the trick but it didn't. How can i preselect an option in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing your `ng-options`  it will store the name of the option in `scope.energy` not the whole option. You were on the right track when you did:

```
scope.energy = scope.energyOptions[0];
```

But it won't work because it expects scope.energy to be the name and not the whole option. What you want to do in your `ng-options` is something like:

```
<select id="energySource" ng-options="o as on.name for o in energyOptions" ng-model="energy" ng-selected="energy" ng-change="energyChange();"></select>
```

The important change is the addition of the `o as o.name`. The 'o' on the left is what will actually be selected and stored in your `scope.energy`, while the `as o.name` is the text that will be displayed on your pull down.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

The model seems up to date but the change isn't reflected on the page. 
I never had this problem before, i think i have this problem because i'm in a directive. The changes aren't reflected in the template in this case. Only the droplist is problematic the other models are correctly updated whenever i change them.

Comment: If i initialize the dropdown with static data i can have a preselection but it seems i can't change with code the visible selected option after.

Comment: Can you put up a plunkr or jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem you are having?

Comment: Try removing the ng-selected you do not need it if you are using ng-options/ng-model this may be causing your problem

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the scope.energy is outside your initialization.

```
 $scope.energyOptions = [
    { name: "test1", id: "Electricity" }, 
    { name: "test2", id: "Gas" },
    { name: "test3", id: "Water" }, 
    { name: "test4", id: "Solar" }];
  $scope.energy = $scope.energyOptions[2];
```